# x86-64 assembly XMM1 register loses its value

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, sse

So I'm working on this kind of assembly code snippet and I ran into a weird problem: the `XMM1` register seems to lose its value in the middle of execution even though I don't think I use any instructions here that could alter its value. Below is the problematic code snippet.

```
    MOVSD QWORD [RSP], XMM1 ;Copy to stack
    MOV RDI, QWORD [RSP]
    CALL printfcallfloat;Prints floating point value from the RDI register, preserves all registers

    ;Load 10 to the fpu stack
    PUSH 10
    FILD QWORD [RSP]
    POP RDI

    MOVSD QWORD [RSP], XMM0 ;Copy to stack
    FLD QWORD [RSP];Load number float from XMM0 to the x87

    ;Do the math y = xmm0 (2), x=10 X*LOG2(Y)
    FYL2X

    ;We now have the result of x*log2(y) in ST(0)
    FSTP QWORD [RSP];Pop the result from the logarithm to the stack
    MOVSD XMM0, QWORD [RSP];Move the result back to xmm0

    ;print XMM0 and XMM1
    MOVSD QWORD [RSP], XMM0 ;Copy to stack
    MOV RDI, QWORD [RSP]
    CALL printfcallfloat;This preserves all registers

    MOVSD QWORD [RSP], XMM1 ;Copy to stack
    MOV RDI, QWORD [RSP]
    CALL printfcallfloat;This preserves all registers
```

This gives the following output:

```
10.000000
10.000000
-nan
```

I'm very confused about what is going on in here.

EDIT: the implementation of the print function is as follows:

```
printfcallfloat:

    ;Value is passed here in RDI
    PUSH RDI ;Preserve value of rdi
    PUSH RAX ;Preserve value of RAX
    pushxmm XMM0 ;Preserve XMM0
    ;Double is passed to printf in XMM0
    ;Now we move the value from the reg to the XMM0 using stack
    PUSH RDI
    popxmm XMM0
    MOV AL, 1;We are passing one argument so al should be 1
    MOV RDI, formatStrf ;Format string is passed in RDI
    CALL printf

    ;Restore XMM0
    popxmm XMM0
    POP RAX
    POP RDI
    RET
```

Comment: I suppose the function `printfcallfloat` might not preserve the content of the SSE registers.  However, as you have not provided its implementation, I have no way to tell for sure.  Always provide a [mcve] that others can assemble and run on their computers to reproduce your issue!

Comment: Are you really certain that `printfcallfloat` preserves the xmm registers?  At least under the SysV ABI, ordinary C functions don't.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping with your debugger to see at what point the value changes?

Comment: @fuz Yes it actually does preserve those values, I'll add the implementation as edit.

Comment: It saves and restores xmm0 only, but not xmm1, and it's xmm1 that you say changes.  `printf` is free to clobber all the xmm registers, not only the ones that were used to pass arguments to it.

Comment: @NateEldredge umm so the calling of printf function does not guarantee the preservation of the xmm register values?

Comment: It may be OS dependent, but under the SysV ABI (e.g. Linux), no it does not.  See [Figure 3.4 of the ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf).  These registers are marked "no" for "preserved across function calls".

Comment: @NateEldredge okay, lemme try this

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer Depending on the operating system and ABI, it may not.  As you have not specified what operating system you are programming for, I can only speculate here.

Comment: And to forestall your next bug, you have to align the stack before calling `printf` or other C functions, or it may crash unpredictably.

Comment: @NateEldredge umm yeah I just ran into a new segfault problem when just adding the pushing and popping the `XMM1` reg :D

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer As a rule of thumb: either keep track of how much you push, or always push two registers as a time (apart from the initial `push rbp` to establish alignment).  Otherwise it is very easy to have alignment problems.  To keep open the option of calling libc functions in the future, your own code should also maintain this alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this WAS a stack misalignment issue and the printf method did actually overwrite the value in `XMM1`. I did not take into account the return value pushed on the stack by the callee of my assembly code (making the stack misaligned) and so I started to get segfaults after adding the pushing and popping of the `XMM1` reg. Just added `SUB RSP, 8` into the start of my code to align the stack to 16 bytes that is the de facto standard it seems and it is also large enought alignment for the SSE registers that I also use in the code. I made the following changes (in comments in code).
The printing subroutine:

```
printfcallfloat:

    ;Value is passed here in RDI
    PUSH RDI ;Preserve value of rdi
    PUSH RAX ;Preserve value of RAX
    pushxmm XMM0
    pushxmm XMM1 ;Added this to make sure XMM1 is surely preserved after call

    PUSH RDI
    popxmm XMM0
    MOV AL, 1;We are passing one argument so al should be 1
    MOV RDI, formatStrf ;Format string is passed in RDI

    CALL printf ;Does not necessarily preserve SSE registers

    ;Restore XMM anmd other regs
    popxmm XMM1 ;Pop the XMM1 reg also
    popxmm XMM0
    POP RAX
    POP RDI
    RET
```

In the main code just added the following to align the stack after entry although I'm not sure if this is the correct method, let me know if I'm doing this wrong:

```
    ;Align the stack
    SUB RSP, 8 ;8 bytes return address
```

Comment: Please also add your solution to the issue of `xmm1` being overwritten.

Comment: Note that `SUB RSP, 8` will be wrong again if you add or remove one of the pushes.  Smarter might be to really align it properly with `PUSH RBP; MOV RBP, RSP; AND RSP, -16` with `MOV RSP, RBP; POP RBP` at the end.  Then you never have to think about it again.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the tip, will add that to my implementation after I fix some more of funny bugs.